# Check if a ComboBox value is selected

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, combobox

I'm writing a form which includes some buttons and a combo box.
The "Ok" button is disabled by default, and I wish to enable it only after an actual value (not the combo box's name) is selected.

I know how to access the selected value, and how to check if a value has been selected - but these two can be done only after the form is close (using the"x" or using the "ok" button - which is disabled).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: It's been a while for me, so I won't write an answer. But can't you check it in the property the UI object is bounded to?

Comment: Did you try using `ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged` Event

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

```
    private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            buttonOK.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

By default a combobox's selected index is -1 (the combobox's name, which you can't reselect after choosing another index), so if you check that it's not -1 then you know a value has been selected.

However another alternative, and the one I use, is if I always want a value to be selected is to use the `DropDownStyle` property and set it to `DropDownList`. That way index 0 is selected by default and the user can only select items from the list and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use combobox selected index changed event

Add this to your InitializeComboBox class

```
this.ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += 
            new System.EventHandler(ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

then in selected index changed event you can check if combox box is selected

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ComboBox cbx= (ComboBox) sender;
   Button1.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cbx.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this had a +1, it actually disables the button when something is selected.

Comment: @MitchTWC if something is selected `string.IsNullOrEmpty` will be `false`, and i'm checking `!string.IsNullOrEmpty` which will return true and button is enabled. Not sure why you think it will be disabled. Can you explain

Comment: I just tried your example, it disables my button when I select an item from my combobox.
cbx.SelectedText returns an empty string. You need to use cbx.Text

Answer (score 0):

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
            button1.Enabled = false;
        else
            button1.Enabled = true;

        //or
        //button1.Enabled = comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1;
    }
```

Comment: This doesnt work `comboBox1.SelectedValue` returns null even when selecting something form the combobox.

Comment: This now enables the button when nothing is selected, it's needs to enable the button only when something is selected. :P
EDIT: Haha I see your ninja edit  ;)